# Compare tables columns(types,collation,nullable...) and update 2nd one according to found differences

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two Dbs on the same server named 'DB_prod' and 'DB_test', and they are simply the same. 
I need to assume that someone can modify table on 'DB_prod'. The script need to find all columns differences (types,collation,nullable,max length) + find new columns, and alter it to table on the 'DB_test'.
There are no relationships between tables.

First step is to find diffrences and I know how to accomplish this.
The secound step would be to move all chages to 'DB_test'.
The only idea I have for now is to use dynamic sql, so write diffrent table 'alters' and execute them in cursor.

Any other idea?

All work need to be done by procedure(s).

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to preserve the data residing on DB_Test? Otherwise you can just script the database and redeploy it removing the old DB_Test? Or you can take a backup of the PROD database and restore it with replace over the DB_test?

Comment: why don't you want to use the tools specially designed for such tasks? For example MS SSDT? You can make automatic publish with it, no need to invent bicycle.

Answer (score 0):

A database-scoped trigger is probably what you're looking for. You can use it to record the alter table statements to a table TriggerLog and then run your stored procedure to execute the statements on your test table.

```
--Table to hold your event data.
CREATE TABLE TriggerLog
(
    Event_Data NVARCHAR(MAX),
    Username NVARCHAR(250),
    Event_Date DATETIME
)

CREATE TRIGGER trg_alter_table ON DATABASE  --database level trigger
FOR ALTER_TABLE
AS
INSERT TriggerLog
  SELECT EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 
        COALESCE(SUSER_SNAME(),USER_NAME()), 
        GETDATE();
GO


ALTER TABLE ProdTable
ADD column1 VARCHAR(100);

SELECT *
FROM triggerlog
```

Results:

```
            Event_data                               Username         Event_Date
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALTER TABLE ProdTable ADD column1 VARCHAR(100);     Domain\User     2015-03-16 09:29:47.387
```